# requests over an open url

Tags: url, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am very confused by all posts about chaining over url requests that I can't fix it by myself only. 
I am trying to take some info from a web page and furthermore open a new "a href" where are stored further information I want.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import reader, writer, DictWriter, DictReader

source = requests.get("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Group.aspx?Lan=Ita")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")


titolo_sezione = ""
table_row = ""
with open("genere.txt", "w", newline="") as txt_file:
    headers = ["GRUPPO MERCEOLOGICO", "CODICE MERCEOLOGICO", "ALIMENTO"]
    csv_writer = DictWriter(txt_file, fieldnames=headers, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writeheader()

for table_row in soup.find("table", id="tblResult").find_all("tr"):
    className = ""
    if table_row.get("class"):
        className = table_row.get("class").pop()

        if className == "testobold":
            titolo_sezione = table_row.text

        if className == "testonormale":
            for cds in table_row.find_all("td"):
                url = cds.get("a")

                urls = requests.get("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Groupfood.aspx?Lan=Ita + url")
                dage = BeautifulSoup(urls.text, "html.parser")


                alimenti = ""
                for alimenti in dage:
                    id_alimento, destra = alimenti.find_all("td")
                    codice = id_alimento.text
                    nome = destra.text
                    href = destra.a.get("href")

                print(f'{titolo_sezione}; {id_alimento.text}; {nome.text}')
```

The variable urls doesn't open any further page. Somebody can help me to make it clear? 
I am stuck on that.

Thank you
Mass

Comment: first issue i see is you hard code the url to do a request on with `"http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Groupfood.aspx?Lan=Ita + url"`. What exactly are you trying to do? I can help you out

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-work some of the logic in there, as well as read up a bit about string formatting. I made notes of where I made changes, and I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for as an output, but this may get you going.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import reader, writer, DictWriter, DictReader

source = requests.get("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/Group.aspx?Lan=Ita")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")


titolo_sezione = ""
table_row = ""
with open("c:/test/genere.txt", "w", newline="") as txt_file:
    headers = ["GRUPPO MERCEOLOGICO", "CODICE MERCEOLOGICO", "ALIMENTO"]
    csv_writer = DictWriter(txt_file, fieldnames=headers, delimiter=';')
    csv_writer.writeheader()

for table_row in soup.find("table", id="tblResult").find_all("tr"):
    className = ""
    if table_row.get("class"):
        className = table_row.get("class").pop()

        if className == "testobold":
            titolo_sezione = table_row.text

        if className == "testonormale":
            for cds in table_row.find_all("a", href=True): #<-- the hrefs are in the <a> tags within the <td> tags. So you need to find <a> tags that have href
                url = cds['href'] #<--- get the href

                urls = requests.get("http://www.bda-ieo.it/test/%s" %url) #<--- use that stored string to put into the new url you'll be using
                dage = BeautifulSoup(urls.text, "html.parser") #<-- create BeautifulSoup object with that response
                dageTbl = dage.find("table", id="tblResult") #<--- find the table in this html now 
                if dageTbl:   #<--- if there is that table
                    for alimenti in dageTbl.find_all('tr', {'class':'testonormale'}): #<--- find the rows with the specific class
                        id_alimento, destra = alimenti.find_all("td") 
                        codice = id_alimento.text
                        nome = destra.text.strip() #<--- added strip() to remove whitespace
                        href = destra.a.get("href")

                        print(f'{titolo_sezione}; {codice}; {nome}') #<--- fixed string formatting here too
```

**Output:**

```
PATATE; 381; PATATE
PATATE; 50399; PATATE DOLCI
PATATE; 380; PATATE NOVELLE
PATATE; 3002; PATATE, FECOLA
PATATE; 100219; PATATE, POLVERE ISTANTANEA
PATATE; 382; PATATINE IN SACCHETTO
PATATE; 18; TAPIOCA
VEGETALI; 303; ASPARAGI DI BOSCO
VEGETALI; 304; ASPARAGI DI CAMPO
VEGETALI; 305; ASPARAGI DI SERRA
VEGETALI; 700484; ASPARAGI IN SCATOLA
VEGETALI; 8035; GERMOGLI DI ERBA MEDICA
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! you got the point I wanted to work out and made clear some steps into my mind. Thank you again!!